# How to combine regex lookaround expressions

Tags: regex, token, regex-lookarounds

For this sample text:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an 1*** English-language 2*** pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet. It is commonly used for touch-typing practice. It is also used to test typewriters and computer keyboards, show fonts, and other applications involving all of the letters in the 3*** English alphabet 4***.

I need one regex expression to match only between the many x*** tokens while stripping leading and trailing white space. If my limited knowledge of regex is correct, then the result should match into two separate lookaround groups.

> English-language
>
> English alphabet

I have two expressions that work in isolation but not in tandem:

```
(?<=1\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s2\*\*\*)
....
(?<=3\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s4\*\*\*)
```

I have tried various ways to combine them in one expression but only got incorrect results. e.g.

```
(?<=1\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s2\*\*\*)\w+(?<=3\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s4\*\*\*)
```

> NO MATCHES

I should  point out that I have control over the token format, so feel free to recommend one based on ease of use in regex. It just needs to comprise a sequence of mostly non-alphanumeric characters so it's not found natively in the data. My guess is I likely need at least two tokens; one start and one end.

**EDIT:**
I have made progress but my regex engine behaves differently to that at regex101:

```
(?<=1\*\*\*\s)(.*)(?=\s2\*\*\*).*?(?<=3\*\*\*\s)(.*)(?=\s4\*\*\*)
```

Results in:

> English-language 2*** 3*** English-language

Why? How can this be corrected?

Comment: Sounds like you just need a capturing group with lazy dot matching: [`\d+\*{3}\s*(.*?)\s*\d+\*{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/tH5vK6/3).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get a regex that matches one or the other? Or get a regex, where the match of one group is `English-language` and the match of the other - `English alphabet`?

Comment: I think for this example I need it in two groups. Problem is I'm using a proprietary front end to regex that matches using named "token" variables of regex. Where matched, the named variables can be used to create reformatted output. I presume groups are used behind these variables.

Comment: Like this: [`(?s)\d+\*{3}\s*(?<g1>.*?)\s*\d+\*{3}.*?\d+\*{3}\s*(?<g2>.*?)\s*\d+\*{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/tH5vK6/4)? With `g1` and `g2` groups?

Comment: @ndn I have varying text in which I need to match between start and end tokens. In reality there can be many (more than two) sections to match, each with the token pairs. I have control over the tokens so my choice of incrementing tokens may not have been the best. I'm pretty sure I need lookarounds to exclude the actual tokens but my attempts only return the last match.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[1-9]\*\*\*)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*[1-9]\*\*\*)
```

You can use this and grab the `group 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/9

if u only want `2` matches use

```
(?<=[13]\*\*\*)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*[24]\*\*\*)
```

Comment: Wow, that regex101 is great!

Comment: @SPB then use `(?<=[13]\*\*\*)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*[24]\*\*\*)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have used more than two matches in my example. Assuming this expression matches into three groups of which I only need two, then for eight needed groups I would need groups 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 & 15.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a regex that will match one or the other, you can just use alternation (`|`):

```
(?<=1\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s2\*\*\*)|(?<=3\*\*\*\s).*(?=\s4\*\*\*)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/pZ1hC9/2)

---

If you want a regex that will match both in one go in separate groups, you can use `.*?` in between and put them in matching groups (`()`):

```
(?<=1\*\*\*\s)(.*)(?=\s2\*\*\*).*?(?<=3\*\*\*\s)(.*)(?=\s4\*\*\*)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/pZ1hC9/1)